# How to get textinput from user?

Tags: c#, xna

I'm making a highscorelist for my XNA game. I would like to make it so that the user can input their name (maximum 6 characters and only characters a-zA-Z).

Does anyone know how I can do this? Popup?

I did Google and got some GUIDE stuff, but i cant get it to work :(

Comment: http://www.dreamincode.net/forums/topic/180164-high-score-system/
Please see if this helps you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check this link for how to store the data.

http://www.xnawiki.com/index.php?title=How_do_I_handle_high_scores%3F

As for the conditions, maximum 6 characters and only characters a-zA-Z, a simple regex on the input would do it.

`Regex playerName = new Regex("^[a-zA-Z]{1,6}$");`

- `^` means "begin matching at start of string"
- `[a-zA-Z]` means "match lower case and upper case letters a-z"
- `{1,6}` means "match the previous item (the character class above) 1 to 6 times"
- `$` means "only match if cursor is at end of string"

Answer (score 0):

Check this out , I hope it helps

- XNA textBox examples: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oC6XhvbM-ts
- Comes with source code: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=j7QHNbjY95U